# How to keep only some message headers and remove all others?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How do I keep only specific headers but get rid of all other headers?

I'm trying to remove irrelevant headers that were set by an upstream `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway`.

I tried specifying a `handle()` function that returns a new message containing only the headers I'm interested in but it does not seem to work. The log message contains a bunch of HTTP headers that were set from the upstream `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway`.

```
IntegrationFlows.from(myChannel())
                // Strip off the HTTP specific headers
                .handle((payload, headers) -> MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload(payload)
                        .setHeader("myCustomHeader1", headers.get("myCustomHeader1", String.class))
                        .setHeader("myCustomHeader2", headers.get("myCustomHeader2", String.class))
                        .build()
                )
                .log()
```

I see there is a [HeaderFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/transformer/HeaderFilter.html) but it requires you to know the name of the headers you want to remove. In my case I only want to keep 2 custom headers and remove everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
class HeaderStripper {

    public Message<?> strip(Message<?> msg) {
        return org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg.getPayload())
                .setHeader("foo", msg.getHeaders().get("foo"))
                .setHeader("bar", msg.getHeaders().get("bar"))
                .build();
    }

}
```

and then

```
.transform(new HeaderStripper())
```

Comment: You can do all of that directly in the `.transform()` lambda or as method reference - no need in extra class! And I don't see a reason to introduce such a first class citizen in Spring Integration. Although it could be a DSL method alongside with the `headerFilter()`.  On the other hand it is now possible as an extension, too: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M4/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-extensions. So, still no work for the Framework! :-)

Comment: I prefer not putting too much code inline in the flow :)

Answer (score 1):

Artem Bilan's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983611/how-to-keep-only-some-message-headers-and-remove-all-others#comment107909280_60993529) pointed me in the right direction for how I would do it inline. I just could not get the syntax correct previously, here's how it looks with an inline `transform()`:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(myChannel())
                // Strip off the HTTP specific headers
                .transform(Message.class, message -> MessageBuilder
                            .withPayload(message.getPayload())
                            .setHeader("myCustomHeader1", message.getHeaders().get("myCustomHeader1", String.class))
                            .setHeader("myCustomHeader2", message.getHeaders().get("myCustomHeader2", String.class))
                            .build()
                )
                .log()
```